# Limit and Average Value of Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

This is a limit-esque question:
\begin{align}
&\mbox{If there is a}\ \epsilon > 0\ 
\mbox{such that}
\left\vert\operatorname{f}\left(x\right) -\operatorname{g}\left(x\right)\right\vert \leq \epsilon\
\mbox{for every}\ x \in \left(a,b\right),
\\[2mm] &\
\mbox{then does}\
\frac{1}{b-a}\,
\left\vert\,\int_{a}^{b}
\operatorname{f}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x -\int_{a}^{b}\operatorname{g}\left(x\right)
\,{\rm d}x\,\right\vert \leq \epsilon
\end{align}
Note that $\operatorname{f}\left(x\right), \operatorname{g}\left(x\right)$ are functions integrable and differentiable on $\left[a,b\right]$.

I'm not sure if I'm interpreting the question correctly, but what I see is a question asking if there's a limit for $\operatorname{f}\left(x\right) -\operatorname{g}\left(x\right)$, then does the average value of the absolute value of the function also smaller than the limit $?$.

This is an especially difficult question for me since it connects limits and integrals closely together, which I've previously not seen before.

Comment: If you add up a bunch of stuff that's less than $\epsilon$ over an interval of length $b-a$ you are unlikely to exceed $\epsilon(b-a)$. The answer below points the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\left|\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm{d}x - \int_a^b g(x)\mathrm{d}x\right| = \left|\int_a^b f(x)-g(x)\mathrm{d}x\right| \leq \int_a^b \left|f(x)-g(x)\right| \mathrm{d}x$$ This question is unrelated to limits.

Comment: I didn't get your hint - could you expand on it a bit? Sorry.

Comment: The first equality just comes from combining the two integrals. The second inequality is due to the triangle inequality for integrals. You can use this equation to prove $\frac{1}{b-a}|\int_a^b f(x)dx - \int_a^b g(x)dx)| \leq \epsilon$ given that $|f(x)-g(x)| \leq \epsilon$ for all $x \in (a,b)$. Let me know if you have anymore questions!

Comment: Nope, I got it!